# How to set the value of a row into previous row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
// numbers 
+----+--------+
| id |  numb  |
+----+--------+
| 1  | zero   |
| 2  | one    |
| 3  | two    |
| 4  | three  |
| 5  | four   |
| 6  | five   |
| 7  | six    |
| 8  | seven  |
| 9  | eight  |
| 0  | nine   |
+----+--------+
```

Now I'm trying to copy/paste the value of each row (just `numb` column) to the upper column. So this is expected result:

```
+----+--------+
| id |  numb  |
+----+--------+
| 1  | one    |
| 2  | two    |
| 3  | three  |
| 4  | four   |
| 5  | five   |
| 6  | six    |
| 7  | seven  |
| 8  | eight  |
| 9  | nine   |
| 0  | zero   |
+----+--------+
```

Actually I can do that by PHP. I mean I can fetch all rows and shift one itam and then update them. But I want to know can I do that by pure mysql?

Comment: `0` should be at the top

Comment: And what will be the last value? `id` with `9`?

Comment: @lolka_bolka What? Where `id = 9` the value should be `nine`.

Comment: indead, the first value is a question, put at the last or use negative id, and so, need a create and not an update.

Comment: See @GiorgosBetsos comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the rows except the max of id will get updated. The max id will still have the same numb. (in this case `9,'eight'`)

```
update tablename t1
JOIN tablename t2 on t1.id = t2.id-1
set t1.numb = t2.numb;
```

[Sample Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcd45/1)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like

[How do I UPDATE from a SELECT in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server)

and use the id+1 for table2.